# generic method with type argument vs creating independent methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, design-patterns

I am having a scenario where

1. A user creates a page.
2. User send the page for reviews.
3. We have multiple types of review like global, regional and translation review.

I am already having a page model.

So at page model i should write one method like `get_reviews` with a `type` parameter

Vs

i should define 3 individual methods like `get_global_reviews`, `get_regional_reviews`, `get_translation_reviews`.

I do not have much knowledge on design patterns. I just want some suggestion which is the best way to implement.

Comment: Without knowing what the method implementation looks like, it is unreasonable to ask for advice on the design pattern... Both approaches are valid; the "better" approach (is likely subjective, and) depends on the specific context of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing more it's hard to say, but from what I can see I'd be tempted to use an `enum` on the model (http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html) to define the scopes for you and keep things fast and clean.

Something like:

`enum review_type: [:global, :regional, :translation], _suffix: :reviews`

You'll then be able to call:

`Review.global_reviews`

`Review.regional_reviews`

`Review.translation_reviews`

You could also send this to a model / collection of reviews from params, using something like:

```
page = Page.first
params = { type: :regional_reviews }
page.reviews.send(params[:type])
```

I haven't tested the exact scopes this creates, but it would be something like the above. You don't need to use the suffix, but I think it makes things a little clearer.

FYI be a little careful if you're planning to use `type` - it's reserved by ActiveRecord so ensure you're not naming a database column that.

Answer (score 0):

I will be more inclined to create a single method for all reviews provided the implementation for fetching the reviews is identical for all types.

If the implementation for fetching different types of reviews is different. I will create separate methods because I like to keep my methods as simple as possible.